# Will upgrading to Windows 8 replace my corrupted user profile?

Tags: windows, windows-8, upgrade, user-accounts, user-profiles

After a bit of structured troubleshooting [I found out that my Windows 7 x64 user profile is corrupted](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/word-2013-x64-equation-editor-freezes-and-crashes/6815dc98-baf8-4a02-93ad-b059918f0905). (Which leads to me being unable to print from Word or PDFs as well as denies me the usage of the Word equation editor.)

Now I wonder:
**Will upgrading to Windows 8(.1) help to remove / replace my corrupted profile?**

As no one in the official Microsoft community is answering my question, I now ask it here.

I wanted to upgrade to Windows 8 for the longest time anyways and have an official upgrade key ready. I just wonder if upgrading will reliably replace my old user profile - or do I have to wipe my SSD drive?

Comment: I think you should just be able to create a new user account on the same windows install.  I would be leary if the profile is know to be corrupt, bring it forward into an upgrade.

Comment: Its very possible the problem will be solved.  Its also possible nothing will change.  If you want to upgrade, you don't have a great deal to lose, be sure you upgrade to Windows 8.0 if you want to migrate your install applications.  The worst case you create a new user profile, and migrate the your user files hand, this can actually be accomplished automatically by connecting a Microsoft account to your local profile.  Be sure to upgrade to Windows 8.1 once Windows 8 is installed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends upon what is corrupt in the user file. Most of the user file is passed forward to the new OS, so it is more than somewhat likely that the corruption will be propagated to Win8. What I would do, in your situation, is create an 'all users' folder and move all of your files into it (that you want to keep), and then create a new user on that machine, and put all your stuff where you want it. Then you can delete the corrupt user. After the corrupt username is deleted you can rename the new one to the old name.